# New verbatim environments defined with newverbs package generate errors when used in math mode

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

The `newverbs` package allows the user to define variants of the `verb` command which can be used for things like applying colors to verbatim text.  Just like the old `verb`, the user-defined variants work fine in math mode.  However, using the user-defined variants in math mode gives the following error on compile:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \ttfamily invalid in math mode.
```

What can I do if I want to define variants of `verb` that compile without errors?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newverbcommand{\myverb}{}{}

\begin{document}
Old \verb|verb|, works in math: $+\verb|foo|+$.

New \myverb|verb|, gives error in math: $+\myverb|foo|+$.
\end{document}
```

When we ignore the compilie error this gives the desired output, namely:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Sid you try this as `$+\text{\myverb|foo|}+$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `\verb` does `\ifmmode\hbox`; more precisely

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 5775:
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi
  \bgroup
    \verb@eol@error \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \language\l@nohyphenation
    \@ifstar\@sverb\@verb}
```

The commands defined with `\newverbcommand` don't do this check. You can fix it by patching the relevant command and adding the enveloping `\hbox` in math mode.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\new@@verbcommand}
  {\bgroup}
  {\ifmmode\hbox\fi\bgroup}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newverbcommand{\myverb}{}{}

\begin{document}

Old \verb|verb|, works in math: $+\verb|foo|+$.

New \myverb|verb|, gives error in math: $+\myverb|foo\\|+$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And it still works when I go back to my original definition of ```myverb``` which stored the verbatim text in a box and then put that inside a ```colorbox```, so my problem is solved.

Comment: @Cian I filed a bug report to the package author.

Comment: @Cian: I uploaded a fix in `newverbs` v1.5 2020/09/02 which got updated yesterday to CTAN. It should be available for update in the LaTeX distributions in the next days.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the verbatim text into a box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newverbcommand{\myverb}{\hbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

\begin{document}
Old \verb|verb|, works in math: $+\verb|foo|+$.

New \myverb|verb|, gives error in math: $+\myverb|foo|+$.
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as yours, but without the error.

Correction: As egreg pointed out, this approach doesn't work for newer `newverbs` versions. For 1.3a (2012/05/08) it works, for 1.4 (2019/09/09) it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try it? The error is still there, because the `\hbox\bgroup` code is used *after* the `\verbatim@font` declaration that does `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Yes, I did try it. It works fine (TeXLive 2019 on Debian). I'll now  try to find the package version.

Comment: newverbs.sty    2012/05/08 v1.3a

Comment: A bit of trace: `\myverb ->\begingroup \newverbcommand@settings \def \verb@egroup {\verb@orig@eg
roup \egroup \endgroup }\def \newverbs@txend {\egroup \endgroup }\hbox \bgroup 
\verb`

Comment: And here the `\verb` expansion which switches the font: `\verb ->\relax \ifmmode \hbox \else \leavevmode \null \fi \bgroup \verb@eol@err
or \let \do \@makeother \dospecials \verbatim@font \@noligs \language \l@nohyph
enation \@ifstar \@sverb \@verb`

Comment: Indeed! It works with my TeX Live 2018, but not with TL 2019 (where I have `newverbs` version 1.4, 2019/09/09).

Comment: Interesting, I also have 1.4, 2019/09/09.  My original code was putting the text in a (color) box, but I found it wasn't needed to generate the error.